# C++ shared pointer on a object call destructor more than one time

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, destructor

I'm studing C++ smart pointer. I have done the following test:
A class TView use a smart pointer to a class TMat.

I have seen that the TMat destructor is called more than one time. I don't understand why.

```
class TMat {
    public:
        int a = 100;

        TMat() {
            cout << " --> TBuffer Constructor called" << endl;
        }
        ~TMat() {
            cout << " --> TBuffer Destructor called" << endl;
        }
};

class TView {
    public:
        shared_ptr<TMat> mat_ptr;

        TView():mat_ptr(nullptr) {
            cout << " --> TView Constructor called" << endl;
        }
        ~TView() {
            cout << " --> TView Destructor called" << endl;
        }
        void setMat(TMat mat){
            cout << "> Setting Mat" << endl;
            mat_ptr = make_shared<TMat>(mat);
        }       **// 1. After this point, the destructor of TMat is called ???**
        void print(){
            if(mat_ptr != NULL ) cout << "a:    " << mat_ptr->a << endl;
            cout << "nb ref:    " << mat_ptr.use_count() << endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    cout << "*** Start App" << endl; // prints Hello Vince
    {
        cout << "> creating cmat" << endl;
        TMat mymat;

        cout << "> creating view" << endl;
        TView v;
        v.print();
        v.setMat(mymat);
        v.print();
    } **// 2. After this point, the destructor of TMat is called 2 times ???**

    cout << "*** End App" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
*** Start App
creating cmat
--> TBuffer Constructor called
creating view
--> TView Constructor called
nb ref: 0
Setting Mat
--> TBuffer Destructor called
a:  100
nb ref: 1
--> TView Destructor called
--> TBuffer Destructor called
--> TBuffer Destructor called
```

1. Living scope of the method "setMat", the destructor is called. I don't understand why.
2. When I live the scope of the objects I expect the call of TMat destructor only one time.

Why the destructor is called more than one time ?

Comment: *I have seen that the TMat destructor is called more than one time* -- You should also print the value of `this`, not just a simple message.  Then you will see that you are not destroying the same object twice.

Comment: you are passing `mymat` by value to `setMat`, so a copy is created, and needs to be destroyed, read about references, as this needs to be passed by const reference, i am surprised that you reached the classes chapter of the book without passing by the functions chapter to read about passing by value vs by reference.

Comment: You pass `mat` by value which makes a copy, and then use that copy to create _another_ copy that's managed by `mat_ptr`.  All in all, you create 3 separate `TMat` objects, two of which you see no output for since you haven't overloaded `TMat`'s copy constructor.

Comment: Once you define a custom destructor, you should follow the rule 0-3-5.

Comment: [Here is your code, but with this being printed](https://godbolt.org/z/Mharc7qsa).  If you look at the value of `this` being printed, you will see there are ones in the destructor that do not have a corresponding `this` in the contructors being printed.  That is because you didn't overload the copy constructor.

Comment: Yes, it is more clear now.  I must continue to learn but I know in which direction. Thank you for all these informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the destructor is called more than one time ?

Because you have more than one `Tmat` objects in existence. Each `Tmat` object gets destroyed, when its lifetime ends.

```
void setMat(TMat mat){
```

You have a `Tmat` object that's a parameter to this `setMat` class function. When `setMat` returns all of its parameters get destroyed.

```
mat_ptr = make_shared<TMat>(mat);
```

This (copy) constructs another `TMat` object, that's owned by the newly-created `shared_ptr`.

But `mat` is still a parameter to this class function, and when it returns `mat` gets destroyed and its destructor gets invoked.

There's also a third `Tmat` object: the `mymat` in `main`. There are three `Tmat` objects in total, and that's why you see the destructor getting invoked three times.